# how to change the default label field name in taxonomy, drupal 7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-taxonomy

I want to change the default label name.  Any idea?

Suppose in taxonomy .../admin/structure/taxonomy/add, we can add vocabulary right.. In that first text box having the label name as name.  I want to change this ?  Please give your idea.

Comment: Taxonomies are not fields. They are entities. Do you mean how to change a taxonomy term name?

Answer (score 0):

hook_form_alter() can be used to change label of name field. Form id of this form is taxonomy_form_vocabulary.